# Remove item and don't leave space in GridLayoutManager Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using GridLayoutManager with a span count of 2 for my recyclerview. I have tried to use.

```
itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

but it leaves a space inside a recyclerview. So is there a way to hide and remove the space inside the recyclerview?

**EDIT**
(Additional codes)
I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to show all the data.

```
private ArrayList<String> mWorldGroupKeys;

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Groups model) {
    String groupKeys = getRef(position).getKey();

    if (!mWorldGroupKeys.contains(groupKeys)) {
        holder.layoutHide(position);
        return;
    }

    holder.bind(model);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      void layoutHide(int pos) {

          notifyItemRemoved(pos);
          //Gave me an error of:
          //IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while 
          //RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
          //android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       }
}
```

Comment: `notifyItemRemoved()`.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error

Comment: post that error with your question then

Comment: hi,you are trying to hide the item what you can do is remove that item from list and then `notifyItemRemoved();` e.g :`list.remove(position);`

Comment: `if (!mWorldGroupKeys.contains(groupKeys)) {
        mWorldGroupKeys.remove(position);notifyItemRemoved(position)
        return;
    }`   try this

Comment: Create method outside of `ViewHolder` class and call it from `onBindViewHolder()`  method. e.g `void layoutHide(ViewHolder holder)` add `ViewHolder` as parameter so you can easily hind/show your view.

Comment: or else you can remove those item in activity before setting adapter

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged(); this function refresh link

Answer (score -1):

You can use `notifyItemRemoved();` or `notifyDataSetChanged();` after remove the item from the list on the adapter. These 2 functions will refresh the list.